Resources for Chess 960 games
Don't know if this is the right place to ask:
Where do I find resources specifically for Chess 960 games?
(Searchabílity is a must!)
Say, a megabase dedicated only to 960. A typical use case
would be that a certain position is given and I look for
high level games. Clearly I can google, say, "RBQKBNRN"
but that gives mostly the positions list. (Very clever
is, say, "RBQKBNRN" -BNNBRKRQ or something like that,
but the results are, well, random.)

We are currently working on an opening book for all Chess 960 variants: https://github.com/stumpc5/chess960
The data was produced with Stockfish 16 and we will redo the computations with Stockfish 17. While we have not yet linked the underlying data, we will do so soon. I could already now provide a link, but we haven't figured out yet the right way to make the data available.
Is that the type of data you are looking for?

High level games: We first tried to use the databases provided by lichess. But there were too few games per starting position and the games where not "high level", so we were not able to deduce meaningful openings based on that data. We thus discarded those and instead only used 20 million games we played with SF16 ourselves.

Yes, that is exactly what I am looking for, especially to answer the following followup: 1.g4 is the worst move according to LiChess Stockfish, with a evaluation of -1.0. What is the worst first White move over all 960 positions?

@HaukeReddmann: I can do this check on the data, maybe over the weekend. Please ping me again next week if I have not posted it yet.

You can downwload games from ICCF.
About the searchabilty: In nearly every GUI you can setup the starting position you need very fast by hand or you can insert a position in FEN-Notation.
Afterwards you can search in the database for this position.
